# Convert PDF to Word document?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

Any software/idea how to convert pdf document to word document?

Comment: -1 for no research efforts. it was just a google search away. there are plenty of them out there...

Comment: pls try to add some more info.

Comment: @tumchaaditya you're right and I wouldn't ask this question in 2012.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[PDF to Word?](http://www.pdftoword.com/)

Looks free, Just tried it and it works well for me.

Comment: it sometimes takes a lot of time to receive the converted document, but it works well.

Comment: I guess you should not use this for confidential documents, as you never know what they do with the documents you submit.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) is now testing a new API feature that uses OCR (Optical Character Recognition) on images and PDFs.

From [Google Operating System](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-ocr.html):

> Google Docs API tests a new feature
>   that lets you perform OCR (optical
>   character recognition) on an image.
>   There's a [live demo that illustrates
>   this feature](http://googlecodesamples.com/docs/php/ocr.php): you can upload a
>   high-resolution JPG, GIF, or PNG image
>   that has less than 10 MB and Google
>   Docs extracts the text and converts it
>   into a new document. Google mentions
>   that "the operation can currently take
>   up to 40 seconds" and a small test
>   showed that the service is not yet
>   reliable: it's slow and it frequently
>   returns errors.
>
> [image: Google Docs OCR]
>
> The results are far from perfect and
>   you'll find many errors, but the
>   service is free and it's constantly
>   improving. Here's the result of the
>   OCR for [this scanned document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grehq.jpg):
>
> [image: Google Docs OCR]

A Google Docs document can be exported in a number of different formats, including HTML, OpenOffice, and Word:

[image: Google Docs export options]

Comment: I read Google Drive will only OCR the first ten pages of a document. I wonder if this is true for this import feature.

Comment: I can't find this feature, anyone think it still exists?

Answer (score 2):

Per my answer on SO to [Does anyone know of a way to easily convert a PDF to a docx format programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192400/does-anyone-know-of-a-way-to-easily-convert-a-pdf-to-a-docx-format-programmatical/2192457#2192457):

> Convert PDF to SVG (ghostscript will do it) and import that...

...the point being that while Word won't embed PDF, it will embed SVG.

Answer (score 1):

[pdfonline](http://www.pdfonline.com/pdf2word/index.asp) does a pretty decent job.

Answer (score 0):

Use an optical character recognition program, like [Omnipage Pro](http://www.nuance.com/imaging/omnipage/comparisons/omnipage-document-input-features.asp) for instance. It supports PDF as a document input and Word as an output.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [OCRTerminal](http://www.ocrterminal.com/) which offers free service for 20 pages per month. They have a Beta Desktop Client that seems to be available for use by invitation (you have to contact them and express interest).