# PDF to DOC converter

Tags: pdf, conversion, microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document)

Hello, there! Could you recommend a PDF to DOC converter that would not insert line breaks on each line, but would detect paragraphs. Or that would not, even worse, convert each line to a text box?

Comment: I don't think you find good one all of these program has problem in some case. if your pdf just was in english and have no pic and table maybe you can find good convertor.

Comment: Duplicate of Convert PDF to Word document? at http://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: you're right, it seems awfully similar to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it but [PDFtoWord](http://www.pdftoword.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **[PDFZilla](http://www.pdfzilla.com/)**: easy to use and the results are satisfactory (although not perfect).

[image]

*PDFZilla is shareware, try before you buy.*

if you're looking for a free PDF converter, have a look at **[Calibre](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/)**, but it will only export to TXT, thus losing formatting and images.

Comment: Thank you but I think, I tested PDFZilla before and each line is either a text box or has a paragraph mark

Comment: converting PDFs AND maintaining proper formating and imagery is always a tricky affair.

Answer (score 0):

Give-a-way for the day has a good one (PDFTiger) at this link [www.giveawayoftheday.com/pdftiger](http://www.giveawayoftheday.com/pdftiger) but you have to act fast. The freebie expires in about 8 hours.

From the readme:

> *Installation*
>
> Unzip the package you've downloaded and install the program by running
>   Setup.exe. Then register the software using following data:
>
> License Key: [...]
>
> **You have to install it before the Giveaway offer for the software is
>   over.**
>
> *Terms and conditions*
>
> Please note that the software you download and install during the
>   Giveaway period comes with the following important limitations:
>
> 1) No free technical support
>   2) No free upgrades to future versions
>   3) Strictly non-commercial usage

Answer (score 0):

One of these will surely do it. A bit of trial and error needed!

[PDF Undo](http://www.pdfundo.us/)

[Comet](http://www.cometdocs.com/)

[Kool wire](http://www.koolwire.com/Messenger01.aspx)

[Freeware genius](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2008/03/28/how-to-convert-pdf-to-word-doc-for-free-a-comparative-test/) gives a comparison test of a few of them, but not Phil Pursglove's suggestion PDF to Word which I have used satisfactorily. I really don't know about your specific needs, but but interested to hear.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) is now testing a new API feature that uses OCR (Optical Character Recognition) on images and PDFs.

From [Google Operating System](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-ocr.html):

> Google Docs API tests a new feature
>   that lets you perform OCR (optical
>   character recognition) on an image.
>   There's a [live demo that illustrates
>   this feature](http://googlecodesamples.com/docs/php/ocr.php): you can upload a
>   high-resolution JPG, GIF, or PNG image
>   that has less than 10 MB and Google
>   Docs extracts the text and converts it
>   into a new document. Google mentions
>   that "the operation can currently take
>   up to 40 seconds" and a small test
>   showed that the service is not yet
>   reliable: it's slow and it frequently
>   returns errors.
>
> [image: Google Docs OCR]
>
> The results are far from perfect and
>   you'll find many errors, but the
>   service is free and it's constantly
>   improving. Here's the result of the
>   OCR for [this scanned document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBCP9.jpg):
>
> [image: Google Docs OCR]

**Edit:** Whoops! [~quack](https://superuser.com/users/12786/quack) reminded me I forgot the last step! A Google Docs document can be exported in a number of different formats, including HTML, OpenOffice, and Word:

[image: Google Docs export options]

Comment: possibly clever and interesting, but relevent?  question is specific to Word, can you get there from here?  -1 until fixed.

Comment: @~quack Google docs can export to Word - http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49115

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Some PDF to Word Converter](http://www.somepdf.com/some-pdf-to-word-converter.html) :

> Some PDF to Word Converter performs
>   fast and accurate conversions from PDF
>   to Word with columns, tables, headers,
>   footers, graphics and layout
>   reproduced just as they were in the
>   original document. It's totally for
>   FREE!

[image]