# How to convert PDF to Ms Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document)

I have some confidential documents in PDF which can contain text, tables, images, etc, and I need to convert them back to a Microsoft Word document. Is there any software that is able to do this? If not, what would be the next best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document

Comment: Ask the original PDF creator to send you the original Word docs

Comment: I'd say *exact* duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that online for free here: http://www.pdftoword.com/

If you're worried sending your confidential files to that website I think they also have a desktop version to download for free.

The result might sometimes not be as good as from Acrobat Professional but it's free! :)

They do the same thing for Excel files and that worked great for me!

Answer (score 4):

The best method I know that can do this, is any professional version of Acrobat

Comment: Interesting! I always knew that Acrobat can convert from Word to PDF but it just never cross my mind that it can also perform the reverse. Will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Scan and OCR.  OCR is pretty good these days.  Usually there's some OCR software out of the box, even with a consumer grade scanner.