# Good application to convert pdfs to word?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document)

I have done a search on google before but all I got was online pdf converters that looked quite cheesy and almost always asked for the email to get the converted doc file.

I suppose there are some more professional solutions out there. I don't really mind if they are paid, however, it would be nice if it was freeware or even better open source. Do you know any?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried many of them. Like NitroPDF. But the best is still [Able2Extract](http://www.investintech.com/able2extract.html).

Sadly, I've never seen a free product doing this, nor an open-source one. One have to pay serious amount of money if he wants to convert. If you need just a few conversion or something, contact me through the address you can find on my profile page.

Answer (score 0):

[Media-Convert](http://www.media-convert.com/) is an online one that does not ask for your e-mail address (well, it does, bit you can wait for the conversion to finish). My preferred online converter is ZamZar but that does ask for an e-mail address.