# How can I convert my PDF file to RTF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, rtf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document)

Does anyone know how Pdf files are converted in Rtf format?

If so, please tell me. It is crucial for me that the conversion is simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PDFtoWord](http://www.pdftoword.com/). I just tried it and it successfully converted my PDF to RTF.