# How to convert PDF to Microsoft Word 2007-format ?

Tags: pdf, conversion, microsoft-word-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/37726/convert-pdf-to-word-document)

How to convert pdf in to word. I need same formatting texts like in pdf to word document.
Is there any option to convert like as pdf (including Tables, footnotes, figures, endnotes, Running heads etc..)

Comment: Possibly, if you have something like Adobe Acrobat Professional this can be done to an extent (in regards to text and then some manual formatting if tables exist). Of course, it does depend on if the document is text or a scan, if a scan then it will need to use OCR which may not have perfect results.

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting? Sometimes when the formatting is not too hard, simple copy paste can work wonders. Other than this, as @DaveRook said, you will need Acrobat Professional, a paid software.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for technology so called OCR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

I have really good experience with [Abby's OCR](http://pdftransformer.abbyy.com/) (can understand footnotes) software or [Adobe Acrobat Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro.html) (better handling with table and export to excel IMO) but they are commercial products.

If you are looking for some free solution, this link might help you: http://download.cnet.com/FreeOCR/3000-10743_4-10717191.html

There are also some online solutions based on upload system and e-mail delivery but I've never tried them. 
Such as
[+] http://www.pdftoword.com/
[+] http://www.pdfonline.com/pdf-to-word-converter/
[+] https://www.easypdfcloud.com/

Comment: OCR will only preserve text (in best case scenario). Formatting needs to be retained, along with graphics.

Comment: Understood, my personal recommendation is to try trial version of Abby Pdf Transformner. Of course that simple plain text is the easiest source format and can be digitize with pretty good results. But there is also an option to set areas in PDF file which contain table, text or graphic, you have to do it manually, automatic recognition provide good results but they are not so precise as user requires (usually). This video illustrate how to select area types and export: http://youtu.be/Mg2G2WTYQyQ

Comment: +1:  http://www.pdfonline.com/pdf-to-word-converter/  worked for me.  Thanks.